# C# WPF XAML binding to DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, xaml, datatable

I have the following tables:

Company {CompanyID, CompanyName}
Deal {CompanyID, Value}

And I have a listbox:

```
<ListBox Name="Deals"
         Height="100" Width="420" Margin="0,20,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
         Visibility="Visible" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
         ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="Deals_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding companyRowByBuyFromCompanyFK.CompanyName}" FontWeight="Bold"  />
                <TextBlock Text=" -> TGS -> " />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding BuyFrom}" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

As you can see, I want to display the CompanyName rather then the ID which is a foreign Key. The relation "companyRowByBuyFromCompanyFK" exists, as in Deals_SelectionChanged I can access companyRowByBuyFromCompanyFK property of the Deals row, and I also can access the CompanyName propert of that row.

Is the reason why this is not working because XAML binding uses the [] indexer? Rather than properties on the CompanyRows in my DataTable?

At the moment im getting values such as

- -> TGS -> 3
- -> TGS -> 4

**Edit** Binding Error Update

> System.Windows.Data Error: 39 :
>   BindingExpression path error:
>   'companyRowByBuyFromCompanyFK'
>   property not found on 'object'
>   ''DataRowView' (HashCode=30295189)'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=companyRowByBuyFromCompanyFK.CompanyName;
>   DataItem='DataRowView'
>   (HashCode=30295189); target element is
>   'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property
>   is 'Text' (type 'String')

Looks like its not converting the DataRowView item into a SuppliersRow

**What would be the best way to accomplish this?**

1. Make a converter to convert foreign keys using Table being referenced as custom parameter.
2. Create Table View for each table? This would be long winded as I have quite a large number of tables that have foreign keys.

Comment: If you add a trace to your binding:

{Binding Path=companyRowByBuyFromCompanyFK.CompanyName, diagnostics:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}

and watch your output window when the listbox binds, what does it say? That might give us some more insight into what's failing in the binding.

Comment: Omg thanks for that! I always forget the output window!!!! Wwhy dont it show up in the errors window!! I fixed it now :) thanks for the tip tho!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somebody kill me.... thanks for pointing out the output window I always forget about that! :(

I found the solution by looking at the output window which was the following

> System.Windows.Data Error: 39 :
>   BindingExpression path error:
>   'companyRowByBuyFromCompanyFK'
>   property not found on 'object'
>   ''DataRowView

I figured out that the DataTemplate binding was binding to the SelectedItem of the DataTemplate which is a DataRowView and not the actual strong typed data. Luckily the DataRowView class has a Row property pointing to the DataRow (which is the supplierRow) class therefore I could bind from there as normal. Fix was in the followign line.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding companyRowByBuyFromCompanyFK.CompanyName}" FontWeight="Bold"  />
```

Changing this to the following worked as I expected it to.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Row.companyRowByBuyFromCompanyFK.CompanyName}" FontWeight="Bold"  />
```

Answer (score 1):

How about setting a multibinding in the datatemplate that converts the row (the datasource from the listitem), together with a hierarchical binding (that passes the reference to the other table from the parent control) and the name of the field in the other table to search for the id within?

```
<UserControl x:Class="local:MyUserControl">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label>
                    <Label.Content>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="OtherId" />
                            <Binding
                                RelativeSource="RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                    AncestorType={x:Type local:MyUserControl}}}"
                                Path="OtherTable" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Label.Content>
                </Label>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</UserControl>
```

In the converter:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter,
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    // TODO: Input type checks

    // TODO: Castings, find key in other table, return relevant field
    return (values[1] as IDictionary<String, String>)[values[0] as String];
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a good, would it be possible to provide a simple example of any 2 tables.